# Need help transferring data between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to keep my project better organized and instead of overloading my `Appdelegate` with data that I want to transfer from `viewcontroller` to `viewcontroller` I want to create a model class to help keep things more organized. However, when using models I am having a hard time transferring data between controllers. Can you show me the error of my ways when trying to transfer this nsstring data from `ViewController1` to `ViewController2`?  P.S. I made this example up , because my real project is a little bit more messy so I apologize in advance for any inconsistencies. The following results in `NSLog` reporting null in

```
ViewController2.m
```

ViewController1.m

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 ViewController2 *viewController2 =[[ViewController2 alloc]init];
 ViewControllerModel *vcm = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 NSLog(@"%@",vcm.string) // this will output a number 

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController2 animated:YES];
}
// this delegate fetches an array of json data 
-(void)fetchedResults:(NSMutableArray*)arrayList{ 
self.array = arrayList;
}
```

ViewController2.m

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
  ViewControllerModel *vcm = = [[ViewController alloc] init];
  [super viewDidLoad];
  NSLog(@"%@",vcm.string);  // this will output null.
  }
```

ViewControllerModel .h
      #import

```
  @interface ViewControllerModel : NSObject
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *string;

  @end
```

ViewControllerModel.m

```
  #import "ViewControllerModel.h"

  @implementation ViewControllerModel
  @synthesize string;

  @end
```

MyHandler.m

```
    //this is where vcm.string in ViewController1.m will get all the numbers not sure if this is needed but just in case .

   for (NSDictionary *dict in responseArray)
   {
   ViewControllerModel *vcm = [[ViewControllerModel alloc] init];

   vcm.string = ([dict valueForKey:@"string"] == [NSNull null]) ? @"" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"string"]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following changes:

ViewController1.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ViewController2 *viewController2 =[[ViewController2 alloc]init];
    ViewControllerModel *vcm = [ViewControllerModel alloc] init];
    vcm.string = @"My String";
    viewController2.vcm = vcm;

    NSLog(@"%@",vcm.string) // this will output a number 
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController2 animated:YES];
}

// this delegate fetches an array of json data 
- (void)fetchedResults:(NSMutableArray*)arrayList{ 
    self.array = arrayList;
}
```

ViewController2.h

```
@interface ViewController2 : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) ViewControllerModel *vcm;
@end
```

ViewController2.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.vcm.string);
}
```

I would also recommend the following improvements.

1. You don't really need a model object at this point. You could just add the string as an NSString property to ViewController2 instead of the ViewControllerModel object:

   @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *string;
2. I would recommend naming your properties, model object and view controllers to something more descriptive. Even if it's a sample it will be hard to understand it if you don't.
3. When you create an NSString property (or any other class that has a mutable equivalent) I'd recommend using 'copy' instead of 'strong'. This will make an immutable copy of the string if an NSMutableString is assigned to the property which is considered a safer approach.

Comment: Is there a way to implement it where the data will be stored inside the model string "@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *string;" and I don't have to write a string property in viewcontroller2? If not, thats ok I just prefer to keep the data inside the model class somehow.

Comment: That's what it does now. What still isn't going to work in your code is where you're setting vcm. If you want to set it in one part of your code (MyHandler) and use it in another (tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:) you'll need to create a property on ViewController1.

Comment: So, just in summary, the main way to transfer data to a view controller is to set properties on it after creating it (alloc/init) it and before presenting/pushing it.